# Geotag metadata saves to .jpeg but not to .tiff in C#

Tags: c#, metadata, jpeg, tiff, exif

I am trying to save GPS information into .tiff and .jpeg metadata.

I have created a bitmap in memory and extracted the PropertyItem from it. My function receives a Bitmap, adds the Geotagging information into it using the PropertyItem and returns the Bitmap with new data stored into it. The Bitmap.Save function is then called on this Bitmap in the one instance using the Jpeg ImageFormat and using the Tiff ImageFormat in the other. When opening and examining these saved files afterwards, the jpeg file contains all the GPS information I have added, while the Tiff contains none of it.

Why is this the case, is the information hidden, how can I include Geotagged data in files other than .jpeg, and how can this be solved? Please help.

Comment: It might be hidden, have you tried opening the tiff in a program that reads geo tags from images, such as Geosetter - http://www.geosetter.de/en/

Comment: I've opened it in "Picture Information Extractor", "Opanda IExif 2.3", and "exiftool", none of which produce the GPS information.
In fact, exiftool even goes so far as to say 'Warning [minor]Empty GPSInfo data'